# How to fix fragment code for displaying Listview and starting a new Activity?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

After following this tutorials http://www.itcuties.com/android/story-of-coding-itcutiesapp-for-android-parse-atom-modify-html-input-custom-listview-splash-screen-load-data-in-background/ and http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ 
i tried to parse rss from one site in one of my fragments and when someone clicks on a item the app will display a new Activity to read the whole article.

The problems that i have is in the fragment code with the setListAdapter and with the intent for starting the activity where someone can reads an article.

Here are the codes of my main activity, the list adapter and the specific fragment:

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1), true, "5"));
    // Now
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Politics
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[11], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(11, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[12], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(12, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new Fragment1();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Fragment2();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new Fragment3();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new Fragment4();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new Fragment5();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new Fragment6();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new Fragment7();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new Fragment8();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new Fragment9();
        break;
    case 9:
        fragment = new Fragment10();
        break;
    case 10:
        fragment = new Fragment11();
        break;
    case 11:
        fragment = new Fragment12();
        break;    
    case 12:
        fragment = new Fragment13();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

    }
```

ListAdapter.java

```
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RssAtomItem> {

// List context
private final Context context;
// List values
private final List<RssAtomItem> items;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<RssAtomItem> items) {
    // Set the layout for each item
    super(context, R.layout.item, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Build each element of the list
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

    // Populate each layout element with the data from the items list
    TextView itemTitle = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle()); 

    TextView itemPublishDate = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublishDate);
    itemPublishDate.setText(items.get(position).getPublishDate());

    // Set the icon base on the post's category
    ImageView icon = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCategoryIcon);
    icon.setImageResource(CategoryMapper.getIconIdForCategory(items.get(position).getCategory()));

    return rowView;

}

    }
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
    public class PoliticsFragment extends ListFragment {


public PoliticsFragment(){}




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // We set the list adapter giving it the results list downloaded from the ATOM feed
    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, RssResults.getResults()));

}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // When an item is clicked a Details activity needs to be started.
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);

    // Set data for the details activity to display
    i.putExtra("title", ((RssAtomItem)getListAdapter().getItem(position)).getTitle());
    i.putExtra("content", ((RssAtomItem)getListAdapter().getItem(position)).getContent());
    i.putExtra("publishDate", ((RssAtomItem)getListAdapter().getItem(position)).getPublishDate());
    i.putExtra("category", ((RssAtomItem)getListAdapter().getItem(position)).getCategory());

    this.startActivity(i);
}


   }
```

The errors in eclipse are in the Fragment1.java

```
new ListAdapter(this, RssResults.getResults())
```

and

```
new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class)
```

What do you suggest me to change?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `this` by `getActivity()` in both case.

***this*** is the context. In a `Fragment`, to attach an adapter or to call a new `Intent`, you need to attach the fragment's context: the ***FragmentActivity*** = `getActivity()`.
The context can be call with `this`, `NameActivity.this`, `getActivity()` or `getApplicationContext()`.